# Where is the trash folder in FreeBSD / PCBSD?

Tags: files, rm

I'd like to delete - undelete files using the shell in PCBSD. But... I don't know where the "trash" folder is. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Just a blind guess: Did you try `~/.local/share/Trash`?

Comment: You can search for the trash directory by running `find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type d -iname '*trash*'`. You may have to increase the maxdepth a bit.

Comment: Typically, the trash folder is only used by graphical applications; anything deleted using the shell, ie., with `rm` is just *gone*...

Comment: @jasonwryan The trash folder can be used on the command line perfectly well. The command to move files to the trash is `trash`. However, it's not installed by default on most systems.

Comment: @Marco Your blind guess is correct. Thank you (If you can post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trash folder is located at `$HOME/.local/share/Trash`. The trash is a
feature of desktop environments like GNOME, KDE, Xfce, etc. and command like
tools like [trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli).

If you use `rm` to delete files, they are not moved to the trash, instead they
are deleted. If you want to use the trash on the command line, the most
convenient way is to use tools like the aforementioned
[trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli).

- move files to the trash: `trash <file>`
- empty trash: `trash-emtpy`
- list trash content: `trash-list`
- restore file from trash: `restore-trash`, then select a file to restore be typing a number